# cocos2dx/coco2d layer transition

Tags: cocos2d-x

I hope to pop down a score panel when players win and pass the gate.
Normally it will pop down score board.
I think the best way is to use layer and pull down it.
But I only get the transition of scene, just wonder is there any way for layer transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not see an equivalent of CCTransitionScene :CCScene for CCLayer but layers can runActions using which we can bring out most of the animations/transitions.

Here is what I do in such situations but I guess you are thinking of the same thing. Nevertheless,

1.Create a layer and add it as a child at a position outside of your screen frame.
2.Then use CCMoveTo to move it to the desired location when you want to pull it down.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in the past.

- Display your layer offscreen 
  i.e setposition(0, CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize().height*1.5f);
- create an action to move it onscreen (I like to use CCEaseSineOut)
- you can also use a callfunc to call a function when it has finished its animation
  scoreLayer->runAction( CCSequence::create(          CCEaseSineOut::create(CCMoveTo::create(1.0f, ccp(0, 0-_screenHeight*1.5f))), CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(MainLayer::scorefinishedMove)), NULL));

Note: that function might need some fixes to ending brackets etc. And you may want to seperate out some of those actions rather than putting the initialization right in the runAction function

Answer (score 0):

For layer transition you can do this:

```
   CCScene* newScene =  CCTransitionCrossFade::create(.5f,Layer2::scene());

CCDirector::sharedDirector()->pushScene(newScene);
```

In Layer2.cpp

CCScene* Layer2::scene()

{

```
CCScene* scene =  CCScene::create();

CCLayer* layer = new Layer2();
scene->addChild(layer,1);

return scene;
```

}